# Illustrator mouse pointer with square or hands

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This morning my mouse pointer in Illustrator either shows hands in which case I can select nothing or shows a pointer with a black square which has weird effects when I select stuff. How can I disable these modes please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mouse pointer shows what tool you have active. Just switch the tool to a different one from the tools window. Most likely you want to use either the black arrow (selection tool, for selecting whole objects, and isolating them) or the white arrow (direct select tool, for selecting object components).

**TIP**: Most tools can switch between selection tool by holding <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd> down, except selection tool that switches to direct select tool. You can allwasy access hand tool by pressing space (can not remember when i last activated hand form the tools window)

[image: Tools window]

**Image 1:** The tools window.

If the tools window is for some reason not visible try hitting tab, or choosing <kbd>**Window → Tools**</kbd>.

Comment: Unfortunately selecting the Selection tool has no effect

Comment: @RunLoop Describe has no effect?

Comment: I mean it does not change the pointer. I have tried selecting different tools and then again the selection tool, but either the hand or the pointer with the square shows again.

Comment: Is the square on the right bottom side of your pointer? If so that just means that you hover over an object (as opposed to a vertex or nothing), thats how its supposed to work. So lets reboot this what do you expect to happen?